# Linux saving a file with a ~

Tags: linux, php

I am attempting to write a php program in linux and I am using either blue fish or gedit. Both those programs are not saving the true name of the file "newaccount.php" but instead saving "newaccount.php~" Why is linux doing this and how can I get it to stop? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like either a temporary file or a versioning feature.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you not to disable the feature..It saves your work temporarily, just in case. Anyway, later you can simply delete the file, if you are running out of disk space...

Answer (score 9):

This is the backup file before save. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit

> **Create Backup Copy**: **Edit** → **Preferences** → **Editor** tab. This option is enabled by default and creates a copy of the file before saving
>   changes. Backup files saved in this manner are appended with a
>   trailing "~". If the user does not want gedit to back up files in this
>   manner, deselect the option.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `gedit` automatically create a backup when you edit files.

see here

Here I created a file called `1`

> [max@localhost ~/zzz]$ touch 1

while typing `ls -l` it showing only one file that is `1`

```
[max@localhost ~/zzz]$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 0 Sep 27 18:39 1
[max@localhost ~/zzz]$ gedit 1
```

Now I opened the file with `gedit`. And Entered the text "hello world" and saved.
[image]

After saving I typed `ls -l` now it's showing two files `1` and `1~`

```
[max@localhost ~/zzz]$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max 12 Sep 27 18:40 1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 max max  0 Sep 27 18:39 1~
```

To Avoid this just follow this method

> 1.open gedit
>
> 2.go to Edit > Preferences > Editor

[image]

Here just change `Create a backup copy of files before saving` to `Autosave files every 1 minutes`
That's it...

Answer (score 0):

Files ending with a `~` are backup files. Normally, you will see it if another program is editing the file or if your editor has crashed.

For more information on this problem, read the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/83032/68865) to [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83026/prevent-gedit-from-creating-files-with-the-tilde-suffix)